# Trigonometric function to radicals conversion

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, radicals

According to [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp(-2i%5Cpi%2F3)(-%5Csqrt(3)-i)%5E%7B1%2F3%7D):

$\exp(-2\pi i/3)(-\sqrt{3}-i)^{1/3}$ is equal to $-(\sqrt{3}+i)^{1/3}$.

How to prove it or what is the general approach to convert the trigonometric functions (like LHS of the topic) to radical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side represents three distinct numbers that cubed will give
$$
(\exp(-2\pi i/3))^3(-\sqrt{3}-i)=\exp(-2\pi i)(-\sqrt{3}-i)=-(\sqrt{3}+i)
$$
so you have your claim.

Comment: Are you sure that it's enough?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Where's your doubt? Each number represented on the left is a cube root of $-(\sqrt{3}+i)$, which has exactly three cube roots.

Comment: If $\omega^3=1$ and $\omega\neq1$ so also $(w^2)^3=1.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg So what?

Comment: So your solution is total wrong because on the left side can be factor $w$ or $w^2$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If $\omega^3=1$ and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are all the cube roots of $y$, then $\omega x_1,\omega x_2,\omega x_3$ are all the cube roots of $y$ as well, possibly in a different order. I'm not sure what's your objection: there is no canonical ordering of the cube roots.

Comment: Yes, now I see it. You are right! It's not so trivial. Thank you!+1